# Change the summary of Established User to be more consistent

Tags: feature-request, privileges, help-center

On the [new privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), each privilege has a very short summary. For every privilege but one, this is **solely** a description of what you gain for at that reputation, e.g:

- Leave comments on other people's posts
- Participate in the sites chat rooms
- Add new tags to the site
- Etc.

However the summary for the Established User privilege includes something else:

> ***You've been around for a while***; see vote counts

This seems incongruous with the rest where all the 'chatty' explanation is done on the detailed page.

Therefore I propose a change of wording to something along the lines of:

> See vote counts on posts and your usercard expands

Which keeps it at nine words, roughly the normal.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you, but I am virtually certain that is not new comment.  It was part of the previous privilege description for `Established User` as well.

Comment: Note: the expanded usercard is no longer part of this privilege.